# docker-compose Verdaccio LDAP

Tags: npm, docker-compose, ldap, verdaccio

Please help me to create docker-compose file for Verdaccio+LDAP. Typical compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  verdaccio:
    image: verdaccio/verdaccio:latest
    container_name: verdaccio
    ports:
      - "4873:4873"
    volumes:
      - verdaccio:/verdaccio

volumes:
  verdaccio:
    driver: local
```

But i didn't find how to add LDAP plugin to this configuration and how to add special volume for builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it depends how you are deploying Verdaccio, but, I'll assume you are using Docker.

There there is a full example how to set up Verdaccio + OpenLDAP

https://github.com/verdaccio/docker-examples/tree/master/ldap-verdaccio

The key to adding plugins to the Docker images extends the official one

```
FROM verdaccio/verdaccio

RUN npm i && npm install verdaccio-ldap
```

That will extends the official installing the LDAP plugin, just that easy.

Then you have to add the specific LDAP configuration to `config.yaml` file like this

```
auth:
  ldap:
    type: ldap
    client_options:
      url: "ldap://openldap:389"
      # Only required if you need auth to bind
      adminDn: "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org"
      adminPassword: "admin"
      # Search base for users
      searchBase: "ou=People,dc=example,dc=org"
      searchFilter: "(cn={{username}})"
      # If you are using groups, this is also needed
      groupDnProperty: 'cn'
      groupSearchBase: 'ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=org'
      # If you have memberOf support on your ldap
      searchAttributes: ['*', 'memberOf']
      # Else, if you don't (use one or the other):
      # groupSearchFilter: '(memberUid={{dn}})'
      #
      # Optional, default false.
      # If true, then up to 100 credentials at a time will be cached for 5 minutes.
      cache: false
      # Optional
      reconnect: true
```

And that's all. Please check the complete example for other minor configuration topics that are merely Docker part.

Aside from Docker, you can use purely `npm`. First of all, ensure [you have installed Verdaccio globally](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/installation) and then proceed to install the ldap plugin globally like this.

```
npm install --global verdaccio-ldap
```

As the last step, follow the same configuration above in the yaml file.

I hope that helps.

Comment: How to you configure `packages` to use ldap group? The example only show individual from the ldap, this is not a good way to manage.